# Bootstrap dropdown on hover

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have a project in Angular the problem is with bootstrap 5 dropdown, I want to show the dropdown menu at the middle of the navbar when hover, the problem is that I'm using `.show` class to make it appear in the middle but this class only appears when you click the dropdown, If I don't click and only hover, the dropdown menu is displaying normally at the bottom of the `li`. Here are some images to show you what i want.

This is how it look when I hover
[image]

And this is how it look If I click the dropdown, notice that class `show` appears when I do this
[image]

So what I need is to make the dropdown work on hover as it work on click because this class is making the dropdown menu display at the middle, here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wggjiu?file=src/app/app.component.html) code, I don't know why the dropdown is not morking on click but I just need to make it work with hover, also I leave you my code below:

HTML:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown position-static me-lg-3">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="drop" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Temas</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="drop">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="../default/">Default</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="../united/">United</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="../yeti/">Yeti</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="../default/">Default</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="../united/">United</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="../yeti/">Yeti</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="../default/">Default</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="../united/">United</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="../yeti/">Yeti</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="../default/">Default</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="../united/">United</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="../yeti/">Yeti</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="../default/">Default</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="../united/">United</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="../yeti/">Yeti</a>
        </div>
      </li>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.dropdown-menu.show {
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 29vw;
}

.dropdown-item {
  width: 25% !important;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this to see if it helps, make the dropdown extend left instead of right. No CSS required, delete all that. GetBootstrap docs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#dropleft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after a lot of reading boostrap docs, seeing what changes on the code when I click de dropdown and Jquery coding I make it work, this is what I did:

So first I notice that when you click the dropdown this change in the html:

1. The `a` element that is inside the `li` with class `dropdown` has the class `show` and the `aria-expanded` is changed to true.
2. The `div` with class `dropdown-menu` that is also indise the `li` with class `dropdown` has the class `shown` and the `attribute` `data-bs-popper = none` is added.

So with this in mind I made 2 functions to get the class `dropdown` and watch when the mouse hover this element, so when the mouse enter I add the classes and the attribute, when the mouse leaves I remove the classes and attribute, and this is what it looks like:

```
$('.dropdown').on("mouseenter", () => {
    $(".dropdown > a").addClass('show')
    $(".dropdown > a").attr("aria-expanded","true");
    $(".dropdown > div").attr("data-bs-popper","none");
    $(".dropdown > div").addClass('show')
  })

$('.dropdown').on("mouseleave", () => {
    $(".dropdown > a").removeClass('show')
    $(".dropdown > a").attr("aria-expanded","false");
    $(".dropdown > div").removeAttr("data-bs-popper","none");
    $(".dropdown > div").removeClass('show')
  })
```

As you can see I use the class `dropdown` and select the `a` and `div` elements that are inside this `li` and add or remove the classes and attribute, this is the simple code:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
     <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="drop" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Temas</a>
     <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="drop">
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="../default/">Default</a>
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="../united/">United</a>
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="../yeti/">Yeti</a>
     </div>
</li>
```

And finally in the CSS I add `margin-top: -1vh` so the dropdown menu is open when the mouse moves to the element, so the final css is this:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.dropdown-menu.show {
  margin-top: -1vh;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 38vw;
}

.dropdown-item {
  width: 25% !important;
}
```